# GPS activity track app with notifications for smartbands/watches

Tags: android, notification, sport, fitness, gps-tracking

I have tested several GPS tracking activities apps, fitness apps, sports specialized (stats, timing) and outdoor/mountain focused in register/follow outdoor tracks (find tracks, avoid getting lost).

However, I haven't found any app that takes advantage of notifications feature to send useful info to the smartband/smartwatch

Examples of expected or nice features:

- Options to customize notifications (triggers and content)
- Notification text with Speed and distance (trigger x minutes)
- Notification text with Speed and distance (trigger x kms)
- Notification when current position is further than x meters from closest point on the followed track
- Notification text with speed (trigger above/below certain speed)

Are you using any app that send useful info to your smartband?

Comment: If any of those send information to the notification bar, you could use [Gadgetbridge](https://f-droid.org/packages/nodomain.freeyourgadget.gadgetbridge/) to have that forwarded to your "smartband" (provided it's one of the supported bands – you didn't specify which you are using). I'm using this with my Pebble and am quite satisfied.

Comment: thanks @Izzy . GadgetBridge is a great recommendation for lucky people having a supported  smartband. However, as far as as I know GB just forward notifications from enabled apps to the watch, so I am still need an app that besides its tracking functions also have options related to  those conditions for sending notifications.

Comment: What is an "enabled app"? I have to explicitly ***silence*** apps I don't want notifications from. Every app that sends *Android* notifications (i.e. those appearing in the notification area of your Android device) is supported. They don't need specific smartwatch support. So if your tracking app uses Android notifications, those will be fowarded.

Comment: By enabled app I  meant "app enabled notifications", and the must be enabled at android level and GB/sync app. Anyway I am interested in sport/tracking apps with an strong usage of notifications and allowing the customization  of  notifications "triggers",etc..

Comment: To clarify once more: yes, the app must support *Android notifications* – but no more. Things like PebbleKit are not needed. All Android notifications are forwarded by Gadgetbridge (except for those "permanent ones" required e.g. for keeping an app running).

Comment: It might be that [FitoTrack](https://f-droid.org/packages/de.tadris.fitness/) might fit your needs, together with Gadgetbridge. Some GB users seem to have that running.

Comment: FitoTrack have similar features BUT  they notify only through audio and not using the text notifications that can be "forwarded" to the smartband. Is there any integration between these 2 apps?

Comment: As I don't use a fitness app, I've not verified that myself. I just saw some GB user mentioning relations (they use both together and would like to achieve X, that kind of mention).